# Create instance of singleton class in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, singleton

I have a Singleton class foo:

```
class foo
{
    static foo* pointer;
    foo();

public:
    static foo* instance();
    static void destroy();
}

foo::foo()
{
    
}



foo* foo::instance()
{
    if (pointer == 0)
        pointer = new foo();
    return pointer;
}


void foo::destroy()
{
    delete pointer;
    pointer = 0;
}
```

I am trying to unit test this class(The class has other methods too which is not necessary here to show).
I have created a MockClassfoo and have inherited class 'foo' into MockClassfoo.

I have created a fake MockClassfoo instance as shown in my test class:

```
class Test
{
 auto aFake =(MockClassfoo *)MockClassfoo ::instance();
             fooAccessor::set(aFake);
}
```

However in my class fooAccessor i want to get instance of foo..delete the pointer and assign my mock instance in it which is not being possible:

```
class fooAccessor
{
public:
    static void set(foo * other)
    {
        foo::instance();
        delete foo::pointer; //here i get error saying pointer is inaccessible
        foo::pointer = other; //here i get error saying pointer is inaccessible
    }
};
```

I do not want to make any change to accessibility of pointer in class'foo'. I just want to get the instance, delete it and assign my mock instance to it. Any suggestions on how to do this since it says its inaccessible?

Comment: You can't, and to be frank, you shouldn't have to. Imagine your class actually makign a *proper* singleton instance and simply doing, `static foo * instance() { static foo obj; return &obj; }` Yeah.. *now what* ? Short version: your architecture will not allow you to mock this instance using `foo` as-is. That's how you designed it.

Comment: The answer is in another castle. Since you cannot do what you want to do, we need more information to help you find that other castle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **MockClassfoo** if inherited from **foo**, make foo not final:

1. make the **constructor** and the **static foo* pointer;** protected
2. define a getInstance in you Mock class that allocates a **MockClassFoo** instead of the **foo** one

It should do the trick.

---

Some hints about your code:

- A ponter in C++, should be initialized using nullptr (or the ancient NULL), and compared against nullptr (or NULL). not with 0.
- I prefer to add explicit **private:** keywords at the beginning of the class
- I don't like the idea of a "destroy" method. Use the destructor instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `fooAccessor` a friend class inside class `foo`. By doing so, `foo` grants permission to `fooAccessor` in order to access its private members.

Comment: I cannot do this since no changes has to be made in foo.

Comment: If you can upload the minimally complete example code, we can help you more on it to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you're not allowed make any changes to `foo`, you can not break this encapsulation.